# IP binding and VPNs

Tags: udp, bind, ip-address, vpn

A problem encountered by VPN users is that when their VPN disconnects their IP is exposed. So I've decided to write a program that will kill open browsers  when this happens. The idea is to check if the VPN is connected every something milliseconds (for example every 100ms).

My question is, will this be an effective method? During the intervals when this check is performed is there a chance the browser will make a connection to the site, therefore exposing the users IP?

Is data transfer interrupted between the browser and the web server? If so will the browser try to make another connection to the website or will it wait for the user to press refresh?

Comment: I think more information is needed. What protocol? How is their IP being exposed? Is it true?

Comment: well kerio and open vpns are being used. I think kerio is UDP. When they are browsing the internet and their vpn disconnects, their internet connection will still be working correctly, therefore the sites they are browsing will know the IP they are connecting with